Binomial expansion for matrices: what is ${\rm Tr}(A+B)^n$?
Let $H_n=(A+B)^n$ where $A$ and $B$ are two Hermitian matrices that do not commute.
I would like to find an expression for the trace of $H_n$, expanded to some order $m$.
For example, up to the third order I can write:
\begin{equation}
{\rm Tr}H_n = {\rm Tr}(A^3) + 3{\rm Tr}(A^2 B) + 3{\rm Tr}(A B^2) +{\rm Tr}(B^3)+\dots
\end{equation}
I used the cyclic property of the trace: ${\rm Tr}(ABC)={\rm Tr}(CAB)={\rm Tr}(BCA)$.
Can I express these combinatorial coefficients via a known formula? In other words, if I look at the motif ${\rm Tr}(A^iB^j)$ appearing in the expansion of $H_n$, there will be a coefficient $\sigma_{ij}$ in front. What will be its value?
More complicated, what about $\sigma_{ijkl}$ for ${\rm Tr}(A^iB^jA^kB^l)$?
Any hints or suggestions are appreciated!

So, you are essentially looking for the number of linear binary strings that correspond to a given cyclic binary string with a given number of constant runs (which is either $1$ or even). For $\sigma_{ij}$, it's just $1$ if $i=0$ or $j=0$, and $n$ otherwise. For $\sigma_{ijkl}$ (and beyond), the new cases arise when the string is periodic, i.e., in this case, if $i+j=k+l$ or $l+i=j+k$, so the coefficient in your expansion is $n/2$. Etc. etc.

You really don't get that much simplification using the cyclicity of the trace, it's a lot simpler to write the answer out if you just don't use it.
